java version not change in flutter
I am having trouble changing the Java version for Flutter. I installed JDK version 22 and updated the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the new JDK 22 path. I also added JAVA_HOME\bin to the PATH.
In Android Studio, I went to File > Project Structure and set the JDK Location under SDK Location to the path where JDK 22 is installed.
I updated the gradle-wrapper.properties file as follows:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip
In the android/build.gradle and android/app/build.gradle files, I set the Java settings as follows:
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    ...
}

However, when I run the flutter doctor --verbose command, I get the following:
• Java binary at: D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189) 

As you can see, it is still using the default Java path of Android Studio and showing Java version 11. I am not sure how to fix this error.

if your java --version shows Java 22, then try File -> Inavalidate caches --> Restart
